# Browser extension to parse and markup text files

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

My requirement is that when a click a link in my browser to a specific log file,  instead of opening it as an ordinary text file, I wish to parse it and display a marked-up version of it, along with other useful diagrams.

Uptill now I have been using python to parse (using regex) the downloaded logs (The log syntax is fixed so parsing is very easy) and mark-up the log by color highlighting errors, re-indenting, providing a gantt chart of the logging threads etc...

Is there any way I can get the same result in the browser itself using extensions ?

Comment: How do you recognise the specific log file?

Comment: It will have a particular name, say "installer.log". I can perhaps design the extension to display all content as ordinary text if parsing fails on the source log file.

Comment: Do you need to intercept a download, or does the file normally open in the browser?

Comment: The file normally opens in the browser as plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an extension "viewer" that would modify how the file is displayed.

A [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) would be able to execute on pages with specific text in their address and modify the page.

Slightly modifying the example given,

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*installer.log"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
```

This would make your content script activate on any page whose address ends with "installer.log", injecting the CSS file and then executing a library (jQuery) and a custom script. You can do any parsing/highlighting from there.

---

Alternatively, if you don't want it to always activate, you could use [`declarativeContent` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) to show a [Page Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) on such URLs. Then the user would have a small button in the address bar to click and activate your extension.

Details are beyond the scope of this question, but it should give you a starting poing.

Comment: Thank you ! This is really helpful to get me started.